# Is it worth saying YES to autosavesInPlace in a read-only document class?

Tags: macos, cocoa, osx-lion, document

I'm writing an app that is a viewer only—no creation, no editing, no saving.

Obviously, then, there will be no autosaving, but is there anything else that returning `YES` from `autosavesInPlace` changes about the world that will have an effect in a viewer-only application?

Or can I delete the prefabbed `autosavesInPlace` implementation outright and lose nothing?

Comment: There is another method similar to this, [setNeedsDisplay:YES]. Here YES is of no, use.... why would anyone call this method if he doesn't want to refresh!!!

Comment: I'd be inclined to say "If you don't know, then no-one does!" Peter.

Answer (score 1):

you need this for iCloud as I read the docs:

"Enable Auto Save. For your app to participate with iCloud, you must enable Auto Save."
"In OS X, enable Auto Save by overriding the NSDocument class method autosavesInPlace to return YES."

because:
"Changes to your app’s documents can arrive from iCloud at any time, so your app must be prepared to handle them"

src: http://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/DesigningForDocumentsIniCloud.html

---

even if you dont plan to use iCloud but you are on 10.8, it is needed as I understand it

Comment: Good point. I should try my app on 10.8—IIRC, the user can drag files into the Open panel to put them in the app's iCloud container, which would make this a viable reason to turn on `autosavesInPlace`.

Comment: “even if you dont plan to use iCloud but you are on 10.8, it is needed as I understand it” For what? Did you find a statement of this in the docs? If so, where?

Comment: no, THAT sentence I 'made up': here's my thought: the user can give you an icloud document from the open panel even though YOU dont enable icloud storage for your app.. im not not 100% sure of this btw :)